# Selecting first row/last row only from saved file to print

Tags: vba, excel

I've almost completed my code where I save data, export as pdf, all that jazz. I was wondering if there was a way to incorporate `[excel sheet].PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "$[firstrow]$[lastrow]";` into my program. I'm not sure if this should be manipulated in some way. The first row holds all the units and the report saves data in each row, however, I only want the last row of data (new stuff), but with the unit row (row 1) as well. Here's my code, not entirely sure where it put it (proably near the end):

```
Sub Save_History()

      'copies data from calculation page
Sheets("Simple Calculation").Select

    Range("A2:I2").Select

        Selection.Copy

            Sheets("Media History").Select

                Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False Application.DisplayAlerts = False`


 ' Check for year folder and create if needed
If Len(Dir("C:blah\" & Year(Date), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir "C:blah\" & Year(Date)
End If


 ' Check for month folder and create if needed
If Len(Dir("C:blah\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(month(Date), False), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir "C:blah\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(month(Date), False)
End If

  ' Check for day folder and create if needed
If Len(Dir("C:blah\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(month(Date), False) & "\" & Day(Date), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir "C:blah\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(month(Date), False) & "\" & Day(Date)
End If


strFilePath = "C:blah\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(month(Date), False) & "\" & _
              Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy") & "_" & Format(Time(), "hh.mm.ssAM/PM") & ".pdf"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=x1TypePDF, Filename:=strFilePath, _
                                Quality:=x1QualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True _


Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 ' Popup Message
MsgBox "File Saved As:" & vbNewLine & strFilePath

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide a picture of what you are trying to do?  `PrintTitleRows` must be given contiguous ranges.  Trying to repeat two rows not together (like `1:1 and 5:5`) is not allowed.  If you want to only show the last row, you would do better to use `Hidden=True` on the rows that you don't want printed.

Comment: You could also set the print titles to the first row and then call `ExportAsFixedFormat` as `Range(row you want).Export...` instead of doing the whole `ActiveSheet`.  This will print with headers and only the `Range` (same as printing selection without actually selecting anything).

Comment: I kind of figured it out? I basically made a new sheet and then did another copy/paste to that sheet. So it prints out only those, but still saves it on the "big sheet"

Comment: Sounds good.  If that's your answer then go ahead and add it below so we know this is resolved.  If you can show the code too that would be nice for the next person that comes on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked (finally) I just Copied/pasted again.

```
Sub Save_History()
```

`Sheets("Simple Calculation").Select`

```
Range("A2:I2").Select

    Selection.Copy

        Sheets("New Media Report").Select

            Range("A1").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

`'copies data from calculation page
Sheets("Simple Calculation").Select`

```
Range("A2:I2").Select

    Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Media History").Select

            Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 ' Check for year folder and create if needed
```

`If Len(Dir("C:blah\" & Year(Date), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then`
    `MkDir "C:blah\" & Year(Date)`
`End If`

`' Check for month folder and create if needed`
`If Len(Dir("C:blah\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(month(Date), False), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir "C:blah\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(month(Date), False)
End If`

`' Check for day folder and create if needed
If Len(Dir("C:blah\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(month(Date), False) & "\" & Day(Date), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir "C:blah\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(month(Date), False) & "\" & Day(Date)
End If`

`strFilePath = "C:blah\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(month(Date), False) & "\" & _
              Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy") & "_" & Format(Time(), "hh.mm.ssAM/PM") & ".pdf"`

`ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=x1TypePDF, Filename:=strFilePath, _
                                Quality:=x1QualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _`
                               `IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True _`

`Application.DisplayAlerts = True`

`' Popup Message
MsgBox "File Saved As:" & vbNewLine & strFilePath`

`End Sub`